# Invite only system for Rails App

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, authlogic, invite

I've been looking into the devise_invitable plugin for use with the devise suite for beta invites, and would like to know of viable alternatives.

I've hatched out the authentication for my app from scratch following a few Railscasts, and would like to know how I can have users request invites for access to my app. The user would do this from an "invite page" by entering a valid email address. The user would then be sent an email containing a password for one time use when entering the app ( the application should compel the user to change their password upon first sign in)

[image: Example UI]

My question:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiqc3.png) Are there any tutorials or resources I can use to construct an "invite page"; without using devise?

Thanks for the help, and guidance!

Comment: I'm sure there are other resources for this but I haven't had any problems setting things like this up in devise. Are there any specific issues you are running into, or are you just trying to survey your alternatives?

Comment: Just checking out alternatives, Devise seems too robust for my needs! But then again, if I used one aspect of devise rather than the entire suite (like a standalone invitable?)

Comment: Actually Raskolnikov, I gave it another go, and I can actually limit the functionality quite a bit; didn't realize I had this much control over devise!

Comment: Yeah it's a very nice package. It works more or less out of the box, although the advanced functionality is there if you need it.